# Hibernate and (postgresql) CREATE TYPE

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, entity

I have pojo type:

```
public class DemoPojo implements Serializable {

    private String demoPojo;

    public DemoPojo() {
        super();
        demoPojo = null;
    }

    public DemoPojo(final String demoPojo) throws InvalidDemoPojoException {
        this();
        setDemoPojo(demoPojo);
    }

    public String getDemoPojo() {
        return demoPojo;
    }

    public void setDemoPojo(final String demoPojo) throws InvalidDemoPojoException {
        if (!validateDemoPojo(demoPojo)) {
            throw new InvalidDemoPojoException("Invalid demo POJO [" + demoPojo + "]");
        }
        this.demoPojo = demoPojo;
    } 

...
```

And a entity with this type:

```
@Entity
public class DemoEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long demoPojoId;

    @Column
    private DemoPojo demoPojo;

...
```

To map type by hibernate, I have:

```
public class DemoPojoType implements UserType {

    private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.JAVA_OBJECT };

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return SQL_TYPES;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<DemoPojo> returnedClass() {
        return DemoPojo.class;
    }

...
```

and in package-info.java

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.TypeDef(
    name = "DemoPojoType",
    defaultForType = DemoPojo.class,
    typeClass = DemoPojoType.class)

package demo.types;
```

Additionally in persistence.xml is line:

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="demo.dialect.PostgreSQLDemoDialect"/>
```

with dialect file:

```
public class PostgreSQLDemoDialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {
    public PostgreSQLDemoDialect() {

        this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "character varying");

    }
}
```

And everything works fine with one exception. Here is a table in the database (from pgAdmin)

```
CREATE TABLE dp.demopojo
(
    demopojoid bigserial NOT NULL,
    demopojo character varying,
    CONSTRAINT demopojo_pkey PRIMARY KEY (demopojoid)
)
```

The demopojo column is a "character varying" type. So it is written in PostgreSQLDemoDialect. And I would like to make a column of my own type "demopojo", which would be derived from character varying. I've been with this for a long time, and the only thing I can achieve is "bytea" type instead "character varying" (worse, because illegible). All other attempts caused errors. Something is missing, but I can not find what.

What should I add to create a new type in postgresql?

Comment: What type do you want to create in postgresql? [Composite / enum / range](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html) or [domain type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createdomain.html)?

Comment: Type named eg. "dpojo" based on varchar (character varying). 

I have the ability to preview a project, which also in postgresql introduces its own type. And this type is in the column type in SQL. But I can not think how it is done. This project is huge, has thousands of source files, various items are placed in different packages. In addition, search by name of this type catches almost two thousand occurrences in different contexts. That's why I can not model it. I would like to get

CREATE TABLE dp.demopojo
...
demopojo dpojo,
...)

without error: type "dpojo" does not exist

Comment: But if its not *meant* to do anything better/different than varchar, why not use just varchar instead? Why do you want a separate type?

Comment: For now, it's just a possibility.

Comment: All in all not a possibility, but a skill.